# Adding custom captions using jQuery to Elementor Pro carousel

Tags: jquery, elementor

I'm just beginning programming with jQuery and I'm having trouble converting this code so that it isn't hardcoded.

I'm using Elementor Pro and I wanted to customize the media carousel to my needs. The JS I'm using is a workaround for having captions outside the carousel. I'm using the buttons to toggle multiple divs to show captions. The same is here for your reference

```
<div class="caption caption1">
        Hello 1
</div>
<div class="caption caption2">
        Hello 2
</div>
<div class="caption caption3">
        Hello 3
</div>
<div class="caption caption4">
        Hello 4
</div>
<div class="caption caption5">
        Hello 5
</div>
```

Edit: My updated jQuery looks like this. Since captions can be constantly toggled using next of prev, is there a way I can store the state of next so that the captions are displayed correctly when I hit the previous button?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var state = 0;
        
        function hideall() {

            $('.caption').hide();

        }

        function reset(value) {
            state = -1;
            return state;
        }

        function updateCounter() {
            state = state + 1;
        }
        
        hideall();
      /*Stuck here with caption navigation*/ 
       $(".next-update").click(function() {
    state = state + 1;
    if (state >= 1 && state <= 5) {
      hideall();
      $('.caption' + state).show();
    } else {
      reset(state);
    }
  });
        $(".prev-update").click(function() {
    state = state + 1;
    if (state >= 5 && state <= 1) {
      hideall();
      $('.caption' + state).show();
    } else {
      reset(state);
    }

        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi, use only one class caption and add id to the item you want to show hide and then make something like this : first - $('.caption').hide();hidde all on click and then $('#caption_with_id'+state).hide(); where yor id will be like caption_with_id1 -caption_with_id2 -caption_with_id3 etc... edit : or use your class and first hide all and then show it like that $('.caption'+state).show();

Comment: Please add your html as well

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(".next-update").click(function() {
    state = state + 1;
    if (state >= 1 && state <= 5) {
      hideall();
      $('.caption' + state).show();
    } else {
      reset(state);
    }
  });
```

Comment: I tried this for the previous button as well by changing the if condition. It worked too! However, I have another question. What if I wanted to toggle between next and previous and the state recognizes my state during slide change?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want to accomplish. Perhaps open a new question with a more detailed explanation of what your desired outcome looks like :)

Comment: here's a link to the new question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64479111/text-scroll-using-jquery Really appreciate your help! :)