# Text scroll using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to create a text scroller to **display one div at a time** using jQuery and I'm very new to this.

I used divs and have been trying to scroll through using two buttons-previous and next. I'm not able to figure out how to scroll through the texts whilst maintaining the position of the scroll.

Issue 1: It works fine if I hit next, however, At any given point during the scroll, when I hit previous, the output gets messed up and I'm really getting stuck here.

Issue 2: The first and the last captions are shown twice during the scroll. I've tried my best to fix this but in vain.

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var state = 0;

  function loadOne(state) {}

  function displayFirst(value) {
    $('.caption' + value).show();
  }

  function hideall() {
    $('.caption').hide();
  }

  function reset(value) {
    state = -1;
  }

  function updateCounter() {
    state = state + 1;
  }

  hideall();

  //alert(state);
  $(".next-update").click(function() {
    state = state + 1;
    if (state >= 1 && state <= 5) {
      hideall();
      $('.caption' + state).show();
    } else {
      reset(state);
    }
  });

  $(".prev-update").click(function() {
    state = state + 1;

    if (state >= 5 && state <= 1) {
      hideall();
      $('.caption' + state).show();
    } else {
      reset(state);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caption caption1">Hello 1</div>
<div class="caption caption2">Hello 2</div>
<div class="caption caption3">Hello 3</div>
<div class="caption caption4">Hello 4</div>
<div class="caption caption5">Hello 5</div>
<button class="prev-update">Prev</button>
<button class="next-update">Next</button>
```

Comment: Please add next and prev, without it's hard to test your code and help you

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen the two buttons have been added in the html snippet.

Comment: There is an error in your code, please fix it so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @SaiZ why does both your prev and next have `state = state + 1;`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I think I've been using brute force to solve this issue. Really sorry, I didn't know what to do there :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope the following code will work for you.

```js
$(window).ready(function(){
    var state = 1;
    $(".caption").hide();
    $(".caption.caption" + state).show();


$(".prev-update").click(function(){

    if(state > 1){
        state--;
    }

    $(".caption").hide();
    $(".caption.caption" + state).show();
    
    
})

$(".next-update").click(function(){

    if(state < 5){
        state++;
    }
    
    $(".caption").hide();
    $(".caption.caption" + state).show();
    
   
})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caption caption1">Hello 1</div>
<div class="caption caption2">Hello 2</div>
<div class="caption caption3">Hello 3</div>
<div class="caption caption4">Hello 4</div>
<div class="caption caption5">Hello 5</div>
<button class="prev-update">Prev</button>
<button class="next-update">Next</button>
```